# Connection between two servers in Java using RMI

Tags: java, rmi, corba

I am creating a simple distributed system using RMI and CORBA.

I have a main server which redirects to another two servers.

The client sends request to the main server which redirects to the other two servers.

The problem is that I cannot make the connection between the main server and the other two.

I made a research and I found that i need an object inside the main server that get the requests from the client and has a references to proxy object 1 and 2(which are actually the other two servers), my actual question is how should I create this proxy object(I will appreciated if you give me an example or a link).

Comment: assuming this is homework I have retagged it, if not please remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Server1` implements `Interface1` and your `Server2` implements `Interface2`, now in order to connect to these two servers you will need to **lookup** and get a reference.

First you will need to register `Server1` and `Server2`, say in the main method of `Server1` you did this :

```
Naming.rebind('server1', new MyServer());
```

then in order to get a reference of `Server1` in your `MainServer` you will do something like this:

```
Interface1 server1 = Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost//server1);
```

With some basic idea, you can read the full documentation at the [source](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/RMI/rmi_corba/)